# Remove Automatically the Lead record after is converted in a Contact

Tags: lead-conversion, leadmapping

How to avoid isconverted, I need to remove isconverted automatically after the lead has been converted to a Contact.
How can I do that?

Thanks
Jose

Comment: Can you elaborate more!! Try to add pics/code wherever possible!!

Comment: When you have a lead and you pass to a Contact, the lead is still there with status Qualified, and you need to activate to check Lead is Converted ,otherwise you will see only a text LEAD has been converted. What I need is to remove the lead once have passed to be a Contact.  The isconverted  is causing problems for mapping, so I need to remove them immediately after pass to contact .

Comment: @JoseHerrera Would you please [edit] your question to clarify? I _think_ what you're saying is that you wish to delete the Lead record after conversion.

Comment: Thanks, after your message I changed the title , I hope is more clear now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

when a Lead is converted using the `Convert lead` button or equivalent APEX method, the OOTB SFDC feature is to

- create an account (or use existing one)
- create a contact (or merge to existing one)
- optionally create an Opportunity
- ALWAYS mark `Lead.isConverted=true`

You can't get around the last bullet if you are using the OOTB lead convert features.

You should be exploiting the OOTB features as your SFDC ecosystem depends on this behavior; converted leads are typically excluded from sales reps reports/listviews by default but will appear in lead funnel conversion dashboards

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, my problem is not with Reports, is with a Third Party for Registrations, is getting the record of the lead is converted instead the contact.

Comment: that sounds like some application problem with your integration - note that a converted Lead record points at the converted ContactId so the third party should be using that if non-null

Comment: Could you explain me how point at the ContactID to check if there is something wrong or something that I can change to sort it out?